# horizontal scrollbar in iframe

Tags: iframe, scrollbar

I am trying to provide a horizontal scrollbar for the html form which gets loaded within an iframe which itself is loaded inside a cshtml page. I added the below code:

```
$('#iframe').contents().find('body').css('overflow-x', 'scroll');
```

This gave me the scroll bar but a disabled one. I mean the scrollbar appears by there can be no scrolling done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You told the element to be scrollable if an overflow exists in x-axis direction. If there is no overflow the scrollbar stays disabled.

If you want the content of the iframe to be wider, simply put the contents inside the iframe into a container with

```
.container {
  width: 200%;
}
```

The iframe should have `position: relative;` set.
Please confirm if this solves your problem.